# Keycloak and istio service mesh fails to work

Tags: kubernetes, keycloak, istio

I have an existing microservice infrastructure which I use keycloak as auth provider. It was working fine up until I enabled istio service mesh for the k8s namespace. Now, all other containers work except Keycloak. My deployment for keycloak looks like,

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: keycloak
  namespace: lms
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: keycloak
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: keycloak
          image: jboss/keycloak
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: 8080
            - name: https
              containerPort: 8443
          env:
            - name: DB_DATABASE
              value: lms
            - name: DB_USER
              value: root
            - name: DB_PASSWORD
              value: "some pass"
            - name: DB_ADDR
              value: mysql
            - name: DB_PORT
              value: "3306"
            - name: KEYCLOAK_USER
              value: admin
            - name: KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD
              value: "some pass"
            - name: PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING
              value: "true"
          readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
                path: /auth/
                port: 8080
            initialDelaySeconds: 120
            periodSeconds: 10
          livenessProbe:
            httpGet:
                path: /auth/
                port: 8080
            initialDelaySeconds: 300
            periodSeconds: 10
```

and k8s readiness probe fails, message

```
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                From                                                          Message
  ----     ------     ----               ----                                                          -------
  Normal   Scheduled  10m                default-scheduler                                             Successfully assigned lms/keycloak-8cccb54c6-7czmq to gke-ing-standard-cluster-default-pool-59e1dee5-d4sn
  Normal   Pulled     10m                kubelet, gke-ing-standard-cluster-default-pool-59e1dee5-d4sn  Container image "docker.io/istio/proxy_init:1.2.4" already present on machine
  Normal   Created    10m                kubelet, gke-ing-standard-cluster-default-pool-59e1dee5-d4sn  Created container
  Normal   Started    10m                kubelet, gke-ing-standard-cluster-default-pool-59e1dee5-d4sn  Started container
  Normal   Pulling    10m                kubelet, gke-ing-standard-cluster-default-pool-59e1dee5-d4sn  pulling image "jboss/keycloak"
  Normal   Pulled     10m                kubelet, gke-ing-standard-cluster-default-pool-59e1dee5-d4sn  Successfully pulled image "jboss/keycloak"
  Normal   Created    10m                kubelet, gke-ing-standard-cluster-default-pool-59e1dee5-d4sn  Created container
  Normal   Started    10m                kubelet, gke-ing-standard-cluster-default-pool-59e1dee5-d4sn  Started container
  Normal   Pulled     10m                kubelet, gke-ing-standard-cluster-default-pool-59e1dee5-d4sn  Container image "docker.io/istio/proxyv2:1.2.4" already present on machine
  Normal   Created    10m                kubelet, gke-ing-standard-cluster-default-pool-59e1dee5-d4sn  Created container
  Normal   Started    10m                kubelet, gke-ing-standard-cluster-default-pool-59e1dee5-d4sn  Started container
  Warning  Unhealthy  8m30s              kubelet, gke-ing-standard-cluster-default-pool-59e1dee5-d4sn  Readiness probe failed: Get http://10.8.0.67:8080/health: read tcp 10.8.0.1:34376->10.8.0.67:8080: read: connection reset by peer
  Warning  Unhealthy  8m20s              kubelet, gke-ing-standard-cluster-default-pool-59e1dee5-d4sn  Readiness probe failed: Get http://10.8.0.67:8080/health: read tcp 10.8.0.1:34432->10.8.0.67:8080: read: connection reset by peer
  Warning  Unhealthy  8m10s              kubelet, gke-ing-standard-cluster-default-pool-59e1dee5-d4sn  Readiness probe failed: Get http://10.8.0.67:8080/health: read tcp 10.8.0.1:34490->10.8.0.67:8080: read: connection reset by peer
  Warning  Unhealthy  8m                 kubelet, gke-ing-standard-cluster-default-pool-59e1dee5-d4sn  Readiness probe failed: Get http://10.8.0.67:8080/health: read tcp 10.8.0.1:34548->10.8.0.67:8080: read: connection reset by peer
  Warning  Unhealthy  7m50s              kubelet, gke-ing-standard-cluster-default-pool-59e1dee5-d4sn  Readiness probe failed: Get http://10.8.0.67:8080/health: read tcp 10.8.0.1:34616->10.8.0.67:8080: read: connection reset by peer
  Warning  Unhealthy  7m40s              kubelet, gke-ing-standard-cluster-default-pool-59e1dee5-d4sn  Readiness probe failed: Get http://10.8.0.67:8080/health: read tcp 10.8.0.1:34676->10.8.0.67:8080: read: connection reset by peer
  Warning  Unhealthy  7m30s              kubelet, gke-ing-standard-cluster-default-pool-59e1dee5-d4sn  Readiness probe failed: Get http://10.8.0.67:8080/health: read tcp 10.8.0.1:34736->10.8.0.67:8080: read: connection reset by peer
  Warning  Unhealthy  7m20s              kubelet, gke-ing-standard-cluster-default-pool-59e1dee5-d4sn  Readiness probe failed: Get http://10.8.0.67:8080/health: read tcp 10.8.0.1:34808->10.8.0.67:8080: read: connection reset by peer
  Warning  Unhealthy  7m10s              kubelet, gke-ing-standard-cluster-default-pool-59e1dee5-d4sn  Readiness probe failed: Get http://10.8.0.67:8080/health: read tcp 10.8.0.1:34866->10.8.0.67:8080: read: connection reset by peer
  Warning  Unhealthy  30s (x31 over 7m)  kubelet, gke-ing-standard-cluster-default-pool-59e1dee5-d4sn  (combined from similar events): Readiness probe failed: Get http://10.8.0.67:8080/health: read tcp 10.8.0.1:37320->10.8.0.67:8080: read: connection reset by peer
```

and the istio proxy log looks like,

```
2020-02-28T10:55:25.880386Z info    FLAG: --zipkinAddress="zipkin.istio-system:9411"
2020-02-28T10:55:25.880485Z info    Version root@ubuntu-docker.io/istio-94746ccd404a8e056483dd02e4e478097b950da6-dirty-94746ccd404a8e056483dd02e4e478097b950da6-dirty-Modified
2020-02-28T10:55:25.880701Z info    Obtained private IP [10.8.0.67]
2020-02-28T10:55:25.881093Z info    Proxy role: &model.Proxy{ClusterID:"", Type:"sidecar", IPAddresses:[]string{"10.8.0.67", "10.8.0.67"}, ID:"keycloak-8cccb54c6-7czmq.lms", Locality:(*core.Locality)(nil), DNSDomain:"lms.svc.cluster.local", TrustDomain:"cluster.local", PilotIdentity:"", MixerIdentity:"", ConfigNamespace:"", Metadata:map[string]string{}, SidecarScope:(*model.SidecarScope)(nil), ServiceInstances:[]*model.ServiceInstance(nil), WorkloadLabels:model.LabelsCollection(nil)}
2020-02-28T10:55:25.881244Z info    PilotSAN []string{"spiffe://cluster.local/ns/istio-system/sa/istio-pilot-service-account"}
2020-02-28T10:55:25.882101Z info    Effective config: binaryPath: /usr/local/bin/envoy
concurrency: 2
configPath: /etc/istio/proxy
connectTimeout: 10s
controlPlaneAuthPolicy: MUTUAL_TLS
discoveryAddress: istio-pilot.istio-system:15011
drainDuration: 45s
parentShutdownDuration: 60s
proxyAdminPort: 15000
serviceCluster: keycloak.lms
statNameLength: 189
tracing:
  zipkin:
    address: zipkin.istio-system:9411

2020-02-28T10:55:25.882325Z info    Monitored certs: []string{"/etc/certs/key.pem", "/etc/certs/root-cert.pem", "/etc/certs/cert-chain.pem"}
2020-02-28T10:55:25.882399Z info    waiting 2m0s for /etc/certs/key.pem
2020-02-28T10:55:25.882487Z info    waiting 2m0s for /etc/certs/root-cert.pem
2020-02-28T10:55:25.882556Z info    waiting 2m0s for /etc/certs/cert-chain.pem
2020-02-28T10:55:25.882634Z info    PilotSAN []string{"spiffe://cluster.local/ns/istio-system/sa/istio-pilot-service-account"}
2020-02-28T10:55:25.882932Z info    Opening status port 15020

2020-02-28T10:55:25.883419Z info    Starting proxy agent
2020-02-28T10:55:25.883790Z info    watching /etc/certs for changes
2020-02-28T10:55:25.883872Z info    Received new config, resetting budget
2020-02-28T10:55:25.883950Z info    Reconciling retry (budget 10)
2020-02-28T10:55:25.884016Z info    Epoch 0 starting
2020-02-28T10:55:25.914398Z info    Envoy command: [-c /etc/istio/proxy/envoy-rev0.json --restart-epoch 0 --drain-time-s 45 --parent-shutdown-time-s 60 --service-cluster keycloak.lms --service-node sidecar~10.8.0.67~keycloak-8cccb54c6-7czmq.lms~lms.svc.cluster.local --max-obj-name-len 189 --local-address-ip-version v4 --allow-unknown-fields -l warning --component-log-level misc:error --concurrency 2]
[2020-02-28 10:55:25.976][12][warning][config] [bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/external/envoy/source/common/config/_virtual_includes/grpc_stream_lib/common/config/grpc_stream.h:86] gRPC config stream closed: 14, no healthy upstream
[2020-02-28 10:55:25.976][12][warning][config] [bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/external/envoy/source/common/config/_virtual_includes/grpc_stream_lib/common/config/grpc_stream.h:49] Unable to establish new stream
2020-02-28T10:55:28.462367Z info    Envoy proxy is ready
[2020-02-28 10:56:01.031][12][warning][config] [bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/external/envoy/source/common/config/_virtual_includes/grpc_stream_lib/common/config/grpc_stream.h:86] gRPC config stream closed: 13, 
[2020-02-28T10:57:00.599Z] "- - -" 0 - "-" "-" 1432 1491 226010 - "-" "-" "-" "-" "10.8.2.28:3306" outbound|3306||mysql.lms.svc.cluster.local 10.8.0.67:49060 10.8.2.28:3306 10.8.0.67:49058 -
[2020-02-28T10:56:51.178Z] "- - -" 0 - "-" "-" 48058 142271 235436 - "-" "-" "-" "-" "10.8.2.28:3306" outbound|3306||mysql.lms.svc.cluster.local 10.8.0.67:48996 10.8.2.28:3306 10.8.0.67:48994 -
[2020-02-28T10:56:50.072Z] "- - -" 0 - "-" "-" 2350 2551 236544 - "-" "-" "-" "-" "10.8.2.28:3306" outbound|3306||mysql.lms.svc.cluster.local 10.8.0.67:48980 10.8.2.28:3306 10.8.0.67:48978 -
[2020-02-28 11:01:02.564][12][warning][config] [bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/external/envoy/source/common/config/_virtual_includes/grpc_stream_lib/common/config/grpc_stream.h:86] gRPC config stream closed: 13, 
[2020-02-28T11:02:08.889Z] "- - -" 0 - "-" "-" 1432 1491 247625 - "-" "-" "-" "-" "10.8.2.28:3306" outbound|3306||mysql.lms.svc.cluster.local 10.8.0.67:50964 10.8.2.28:3306 10.8.0.67:50962 -
[2020-02-28T11:01:59.772Z] "- - -" 0 - "-" "-" 48058 142271 256746 - "-" "-" "-" "-" "10.8.2.28:3306" outbound|3306||mysql.lms.svc.cluster.local 10.8.0.67:50908 10.8.2.28:3306 10.8.0.67:50906 -
[2020-02-28T11:01:58.988Z] "- - -" 0 - "-" "-" 2350 2551 257532 - "-" "-" "-" "-" "10.8.2.28:3306" outbound|3306||mysql.lms.svc.cluster.local 10.8.0.67:50902 10.8.2.28:3306 10.8.0.67:50900 -
[2020-02-28 11:07:05.000][12][warning][config] [bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/external/envoy/source/common/config/_virtual_includes/grpc_stream_lib/common/config/grpc_stream.h:86] gRPC config stream closed: 13,
```

any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Hi, what version of Istio do You have? If You have mTLS enabled, did You create `DestinationRule` for the database?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this annotation fixed the issue for me spec:

      annotations:
        sidecar.istio.io/rewriteAppHTTPProbers: "true"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a lot of headaches, I figured out that the server actually starts fine and it is accessible from inside the pod. Since the health check forces the container to be recreated, the actual RC becomes misleading. Eventually,     sidecar.istio.io/rewriteAppHTTPProbers: "true" fixed the issue.

```
 spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: keycloak
      annotations:
        sidecar.istio.io/rewriteAppHTTPProbers: "true"
```

Comment: I was getting the same error as you. I added the annotation as you did, but now I get the error. `failed accepting connection from peer Socket[addr=/127.0.0.6,port=34575,localport=7800]: java.io.EOFException` Any ideas?